# Keycloack Client conditional redirect

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to create a provider for An optional redirect, if a user from a specific client tries to access or log in, we could choose to redirect him to an error or maintenance page instead.

So in the Keycloak admin dashboard, under a specific client, we can choose to toggle the client into the maintenance page.

Then users attempting to log in or those who are already logged in will be redirected to a maintenance page.

It would be great if there was a way I could use it right now from the Keycloak side.